# BadRequest on request with nonexistent filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a question. 
Is there a way in ASP.NET core to return a `BadRequestResult` on calling REST API controller if request contains filter that does not exist ?

Sample method deifnition
`public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers(string cardNr)`

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an action filter that check if the query parameters match the action arguments :

```
public class ValidateQueryFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var queryKeys = context.HttpContext.Request.Query.Keys;
        var args = context.ActionArguments;
        if (queryKeys.Any(k => !args.ContainsKey(k)))
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

And add this attribute on the actions where you want the arguments validation

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think you have supplied example for ASP.NET (not core). I don't have `HttpActionContext ` class in filters but `ActionExecutingContext` which doesn't have in turn `Request` and `Response` properties.

Comment: Sorry you are right I gave the version for ASP.NET Framework not Core. I updated my answer for ASP.NET Core